# How to sort an array in a particular order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an `associative array` that I need to sort in a particular order. Each object has a `description` key. Here is the current array I want to rearrange.

```js
[{
    id: "1",
    permission: "Administer Source List",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "*",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    permission: "Administer Common Layers",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "*",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    permission: "Create Campaigns",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    permission: "Access/modify campaign setup",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "*",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "11",
    permission: "View Reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "*",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "12",
    permission: "Modify prebuilt reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "16",
    permission: "Create portfolio",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "17",
    permission: "Access all portfolios (at org)",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "*",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "20",
    permission: "Administer role templates for org",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "21",
    permission: "Add/edit/delete non org-admin users at org",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: "*"
  },
  {
    id: "25",
    permission: "Administer organizations & survey programs",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "26",
    permission: "Administer all users in system",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Data Source",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Campaigns",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "APT",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Manage Users",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "ABC Admin functions",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  }
];
```

I want to resort the array to be like this:

```js
[{
    permission: "Data Source",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    permission: "Administer Source List",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "*",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    permission: "Administer Common Layers",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "*",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Campaigns",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    permission: "Create Campaigns",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    permission: "Access/modify campaign setup",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "*",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "11",
    permission: "View Reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "*",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "12",
    permission: "Modify prebuilt reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "APT",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "16",
    permission: "Create portfolio",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "17",
    permission: "Access all portfolios (at org)",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "*",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Manage Users",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "20",
    permission: "Administer role templates for org",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "21",
    permission: "Add/edit/delete non org-admin users at org",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: "*"
  },
  {
    permission: "ABC Admin functions",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "25",
    permission: "Administer organizations & survey programs",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "26",
    permission: "Administer all users in system",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  }
];
```

Is there away I can use the `description` key to make this happen?

Comment: *Is there a way*? Yes. Its not right to say but a user with your rep should know how to ask question.

Comment: Yes of course. It looks like you want to sort on description and ID? In which case you need two sorts.

Comment: @NagaveerGowda This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a map of descriptions and their order. Use that map in your `sort` comparator , Try the following:

```js
let arr = [ { id: "1", permission: "Administer Source List", description: "Data Source", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "*", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "2", permission: "Administer Common Layers", description: "Data Source", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "*", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "7", permission: "Create Campaigns", description: "Campaigns", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "8", permission: "Access/modify campaign setup", description: "Campaigns", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "*", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "11", permission: "View Reports", description: "Reports", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "*", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "12", permission: "Modify prebuilt reports", description: "Reports", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "16", permission: "Create portfolio", description: "APT", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "17", permission: "Access all portfolios (at org)", description: "APT", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "*", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "20", permission: "Administer role templates for org", description: "Manage Users", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "21", permission: "Add/edit/delete non org-admin users at org", description: "Manage Users", OrgAdmin: "*", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "*" }, { id: "25", permission: "Administer organizations & survey programs", description: "ABC Admin functions", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { id: "26", permission: "Administer all users in system", description: "ABC Admin functions", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { permission: "Data Source", description: "Data Source", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { permission: "Campaigns", description: "Campaigns", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { permission: "Reports", description: "Reports", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { permission: "APT", description: "APT", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { permission: "Manage Users", description: "Manage Users", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" }, { permission: "ABC Admin functions", description: "ABC Admin functions", OrgAdmin: "", DataAdmin: "", SetupAdmin: "", DataConsumer: "", APTUser: "", UserAdmin: "" } ];
let map = {
  "Data Source"  : 1,
  "Campaigns" : 2,
  "Reports" : 3,
  "APT" : 4,
  "Manage Users" : 5,
  "ABC Admin functions" : 6,
};

arr.sort((a,b) => map[a.description] - map[b.description]);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and pass it a custom sorter function to sort any type of items either on its own value (if it's a number or a string) or on any of its keys (if the items are objects).

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>   the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order
>   is according to string Unicode code points.

To customise behaviour of `sort()` method, we can pass it a sorter function. This sorter function accepts 2 parameters, which represent the elements from the array. We need to return `-1`, `1` or `0` in this sorter function, where `1` indicates that the first element should be placed before the second element, `-1` indicates that second element should be placed before the second and `0` indicates that both elements can be considered equal.

```js
var unsortedArray = [
  {
    id: "1",
    permission: "Administer Source List",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "*",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    permission: "Administer Common Layers",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "*",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    permission: "Create Campaigns",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    permission: "Access/modify campaign setup",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "*",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "11",
    permission: "View Reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "*",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "12",
    permission: "Modify prebuilt reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "16",
    permission: "Create portfolio",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "17",
    permission: "Access all portfolios (at org)",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "*",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "20",
    permission: "Administer role templates for org",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "21",
    permission: "Add/edit/delete non org-admin users at org",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "*",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: "*"
  },
  {
    id: "25",
    permission: "Administer organizations & survey programs",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    id: "26",
    permission: "Administer all users in system",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Data Source",
    description: "Data Source",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Campaigns",
    description: "Campaigns",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Reports",
    description: "Reports",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "APT",
    description: "APT",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "Manage Users",
    description: "Manage Users",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  },
  {
    permission: "ABC Admin functions",
    description: "ABC Admin functions",
    OrgAdmin: "",
    DataAdmin: "",
    SetupAdmin: "",
    DataConsumer: "",
    APTUser: "",
    UserAdmin: ""
  }
];

// array is not sorted yet
// console.log( unsortedArray );

unsortedArray.sort(function(a, b){
  // this is the custom sorter function
  return a['description'].localeCompare(b['description']);
});

// array should now be sorted
console.log( unsortedArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use `Array.sort()`.  If all you care about is `description` you could do:

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => a.description < b.description ? -1 : 1)
```

You can make the sort function more complex if it is necessary to consider other keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function, that will take key value as `description` or whichever key value you want, and sort the whole data accordingly.

in html call as

```
<button onClick="sortData('description')" >Click To Sort</button>
<button onClick="sortData('id')" >Click To Sort</button>
<button onClick="sortData('permission')" >Click To Sort</button>
<button onClick="sortData('userAdmin')" >Click To Sort</button>
```

and add this function to .js

```
sortData(key: any) {
this.data.sort(function (name1, name2) {
  if (name1[key] > name2[key]) {
    return -1;
  } else if (name1[key] < name2[key]) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
}
```

this will sort the array , and where ever you want, display the array after its sorted after the click.